# How do I fix type annotations needed for `&Target` error for rust's hyper make_service_fn

Tags: rust, reverse-proxy, hyper

My 20th day learning Rust and I try to code a reverse proxy that can authenticate.

Got error in line 30: error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `&Target`. I tried to follow the help by compiler "consider giving this closure parameter an explicit type where the type for type parameter `Target` is specified"

But i got even more errors and confuse.

Please help.

```
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::net::{IpAddr, SocketAddr};

async fn authenticate(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Request<Body>, Infallible> {
    // Perform authentication checks here.
    // For example, you can check for a valid API key in the request header.

    Ok(req)
}

async fn handle(client_ip: IpAddr, req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    // Forward the request to another server.
    let target_url = "http://127.0.0.1:13901";
    match hyper_reverse_proxy::call(client_ip, target_url, req).await {
        Ok(response) => Ok(response),
        Err(error) => {
            // println!("Error forwarding request: {}", error);
            Ok(Response::builder()
                .status(hyper::StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(Body::empty())
                .unwrap())
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let make_service = make_service_fn(|conn| async {  // <<-- Error!
        let client_ip = conn.remote_addr().ip();
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |req| {
            let client_ip = client_ip.clone();
            async {
                match authenticate(req).await {
                    Ok(req) => handle(client_ip, req).await,
                    Err(_) => {
                        eprintln!("Authentication failed");
                        Ok(Response::builder()
                            .status(hyper::StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED)
                            .body(Body::empty())
                            .unwrap())
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    });

    let bind_addr = "127.0.0.1:8000";
    let addr: SocketAddr = bind_addr.parse().expect("Could not parse ip:port.");

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_service);
    println!("Running reverse proxy on {:?}", addr);

    if let Err(error) = server.await {
        eprintln!("Error running server: {}", error);
    }
}
```

my cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
hyper-reverse-proxy = "0.5"
hyper = { version = "0.14", features = ["full"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

the signature of the functions is

```rust
pub fn make_service_fn<F, Target, Ret>(f: F) -> MakeServiceFn<F>
where
    F: FnMut(&Target) -> Ret,
    Ret: Future,
```

The target is a generic parameter and according to example from documentation

```rust
use std::convert::Infallible;
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use hyper::server::conn::AddrStream;
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};

let addr = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into();

let make_svc = make_service_fn(|socket: &AddrStream| {
    let remote_addr = socket.remote_addr();
    async move {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_: Request<Body>| async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(
                Response::new(Body::from(format!("Hello, {}!", remote_addr)))
            )
        }))
    }
});

// Then bind and serve...
let server = Server::bind(&addr)
    .serve(make_svc);

// Finally, spawn `server` onto an Executor...
if let Err(e) = server.await {
    eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
}
```

we can pass reference to `AddrStream` which you have to specify since rust cannot infer this...

so the fixed code looks like this

```rust
    let make_service = make_service_fn(|conn: &AddrStream| {
        let client_ip = conn.remote_addr().ip();
        async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |req| {
                let client_ip = client_ip.clone();
                async move {
                    match authenticate(req).await {
                        Ok(req) => handle(client_ip, req).await,
                        Err(_) => {
                            eprintln!("Authentication failed");
                            Ok(Response::builder()
                                .status(hyper::StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED)
                                .body(Body::empty())
                                .unwrap())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }))
        }
    });
```